# How to configure IIS SMTP for sending Mails to Microsoft Emails Without Microsoft SMTP Credentials?

Tags: smtp, iis-6, mail-server

How can I send authentication emails to Microsoft email addresses without using Microsoft SMTP credentials, solely relying on the IIS IP address? I need a comprehensive step-by-step guide for accomplishing this task?

1. I tried Configuring Email SMTP in IIS which is sending mail but mail is getting saved in pickup directory as you can see in blow SS . Now how can we send this email to Microsoft ?
   [IIS Email SMTP Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeUOL.png)
   ,  [Pickup Directory Mail got saved But not sent to Microsoft mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ocf7.png)
2. I also configuring IIS 6.0 server Manager but it's only using port 25 which is not sending mail to Microsoft .